# sqlcipher framework not found when integrating Crashlytics in a Worklight application

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, crashlytics

I tried to integrate Crashlytics for iOS into an IBM Worklight 6.1 project, but I have got an error related to sqlcipher.framework.

Does this means that Crashlytics and Worklight are not compatible?

For info, you can know more about Crashlytics at: https://get.fabric.io/crashlytics

The error that I am getting is:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/Users/myUsername/MyProjectPath/ProjectName/apps/AppName/iphone/native/Frameworks"'
ld: framework not found sqlcipher
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Why don't you provide the error and a project what this is happening...?

Comment: @IdanAdar Just tested again and provided the error. I think that there are some conflicts between Fabric CrashLytics and Worklight/SqlCipher frameworks. Do you confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work in a Hyrid app.

1. Follow the steps provided by the Crashlytics "installer"
2. Once you get the error about sqlcipher.framework
3. Open Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries
4. Find sqlcipher.framework in the list and drag it to the top
5. Press CMD+B again

Should pass this time.