# How to integrate IBM Mobilefirst platform with Crashlytics?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, crashlytics

I wanted to know how to integerate Crashlytics with ibm mobilefirst project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no special instructions to integrate Crashlytics with a MobileFirst Platform-based app.

- If you've created a Native app, you have a native app and this is not related to MFP.
- If you've created a Hybrid app, you need to open the generated project in Xcode and follow Crashlytics instructions (on how to integrate their SDK...) as you would with any other Xcode project.

You may encounter an error regarding SQLCipher. See here: [sqlcipher framework not found when integrating Crashlytics in a Worklight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420614/sqlcipher-framework-not-found-when-integrating-crashlytics-in-a-worklight-applic)

Comment: I wanted to integrate an android application (hybrid) with crashlytics.. From your response can I assume that I need to try to integrate Crashlytics sdk with android project in eclipse ?

Comment: It should be the same with Android.

Comment: I read somewhere in IBM portal about Automated crash analytics in  ?  Can anyone say how to use it with my mobilefirst platform project ?